# What is the equivalent of camera.matrixWorld.getPosition().x using the getPositionFromMatrix

Tags: javascript, three.js

I had a good method for obtaining the x position of the camera along a path; however looking at the console, it appears to be deprecated, and so I am looking to update my functions with the new form.

I was using camera.matrixWorld.getPosition().x

Using getPositionFromMatrix, how do I obtain the x value of the camera position?

i tried this, but it did not work

```
var thisvect = new THREE.Vector3();
thisvect.getPositionFromMatrix(this.object);
var thisx = thisvect.x;
```

i also tried this, but it did not work

```
var thisvect = new THREE.Vector3();
thisvect.getPositionFromMatrix(this.object);
var thisx = thisvect[0];
```

Thanks

Comment: I can see from the docs that because camera inherits from object3d, it still has a matrixWorld property. would this work? `thisvect.getPositionFromMatrix(camera.matrixWorld);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the matrix:

```
thisvect.getPositionFromMatrix( this.object.matrixWorld );
```

Comment: Thanks I shall give it a try :)